# When we declare a class without extending any class , does it have parent class?

Tags: java, class, oop

When we declare a class without extending any class , does it have parent class in java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes and in almost all OO languages a class with no explicit extension, implicitly extends the base class, usualy called `Object`

reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

> Excepting `Object`, which has no superclass, every class has one and
>   only one direct superclass (single inheritance). In the absence of any
>   other explicit superclass, every class is implicitly a subclass of
>   `Object`.